# Why doesn't the loop index decrementing in python3 work?

Tags: python

I need to decrement the loop index inside a for loop. Why doesnt the i -= 1 work?

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
    if i == 2:
        i -= 1
```

the output is

```
0
1
2
```

instead of

```
0
1
2
2
.
.
```

Comment: Use the while loop instead of for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be under the misconception that `for i in range(n): ...` is just syntactic sugar for this:

```
i=0
while i < n:
    ...  # loop body here
    i+=1
```

Instead the thing you're iterating over gets asked for new values every time. The real expansion is something like this:

```
iterator = iter(range(3))
while True:
    try:
        i = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    ...  # loop body here
```

You can see how changing `i` in the `...` block does nothing here, because in the next loop iteration we just ask `iterator` (in this case a `range_iterator`) for a new value without respect for the new one.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop uses `iterator`, you cannot modify iterator in this fashion. The simplest solution is to use a `while` loop like :

```
i = 0
while i < 3:
    print(i)
    if i == 2:
        i -= 1
    i += 1
```